An inequality possibly of isoperimetric nature
I am trying to prove the following inequality, which I suspect to have an isoperimetric interpretation: let $\theta\in \operatorname{BV}(S^1)$. Is it true that
$$
\left(\int_{S^1} \cos\theta(s)\, ds\right)^2 + \left(\int_{S^1} \sqrt{\sin^2\theta(s) + \theta'^2(s)}\, ds\right)^2 \ge 4\pi^2?
$$
Note two cases in which equality holds: (1) $\theta(s)$ is constant, and (ii) $\theta(s)\in\{0,\pi\}$ switching values at $s=0,\pi$.

Apologies. I corrected the $dx$ into $ds$. The integral is well-defined for $\theta\in W^{1,1}$.

Have you tried the Euler-Lagrange equations? That is one way to establish the standard isoperimetric inequality. Also: in case (ii), are you accounting for $\theta'$ being a Dirac delta distribution at the switching points?

@Jeff Not sure that the EL equations can help here. As for the second question, yes, at points of discontinuity the absolute value of jump will add to the integral.

in your second case of equality: the first term is zero, while the second term should be \pi^2, so the sum is \pi^2; am I missing something?

oh of course, you have to jump twice so you get (2\pi)^2

Why not use EL? You are essentially trying to minimize the left hand side over $\theta$...

My other question was because the "switching" should cost you something, compared to setting $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$ everywhere, due to the $\theta'^2$ term. I would expect (ii) to be more expensive (i.e., give a larger value).

Another way to put it, your second example has discontinuities at $s=0,\pi$, so it does not belong to $W^{1,1}$. How do you interpret $\theta'$?

@Jeff: It is obviously not possible to reach the minimal value with a $\theta\in W^{1,1}$ that has a range of diameter $\ge\pi$ (since $\int |\theta'| \ge 2\pi$ already). However, we can come arbitrarily close by approximating the step function, and I think this is what the OP had in mind.

I fixed the range into BV. I think that this resolves all (justified) concerns above.

@RazKupferman: I personally think the previous version was cleaner. Now you'd have to provide a separate explanation what you mean by the second term if you want to be careful.

@ChristianRemling The current formulation looks the only one to make sense. At jump points, the second integral contributes the absolute value of the jump. In principle, we could even assume that $\theta(s)$ is smooth (they are dense), but I don't think this adds to clarity.

@RazKupferman : I think it is the best to just assume that $\theta$ is smooth. Indeed, if $\theta$ is e.g. a Cantor function of bounded variation, what would $\theta'$ be assumed to be?

@IosifPinelis: I think the problem is fine if $\theta'$ is interpreted in distributional sense (that is, $\theta'=\mu$, the measure whose integral is $\theta$), and then we split off the singular part and declare $\sqrt{ \ldots }, ds = d\mu_s$ on a support of $\mu_s$. But why make it hard on ourselves when either smooth $\theta$ or $\theta\in W^{1,1}$ is an equivalent formulation that avoids these hassles?
